# Creating a New Job Inside a Multibranch Pipeline Using the API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have a Multibranch Pipeline for which I've disabled auto scanning of branches. I'd like to **create** (not trigger) jobs inside this Multibranch from another, unrelated job, using the Jenkins API or any other way.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

yep, you can use Jenkins Job DSL. Write a job DSL groovy file in your repo defining the jobs you want to create, and then run the dsl via: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/job-dsl/#-jobdsl-%20process%20job%20dsls

Comment: Will that work for jobs *inside* a multibranch pipeline job (which is a "computer folder")?

Comment: yep, should work. feel free to post some code and I can take a look